# Save an django email to eml

Tags: python, django, file, email

I am generating a bunch of html emails in django, and I want to save them into a model, in a FileField.  I can quite easily generate the html content and dump in into a `File`, but I want to create something that can be opened in email clients, e.g. an eml file.  Does anyone know of a python or django module to do this?  Just to be clear, I'm not looking for an alternative email backend, as I also want the emails to be sent when they're generated.

**Edit:** After a bit of reading, it looks to me like the `EmailMessage.messge()` should return the content that should be stored int he eml file.  However, if I try to save it like this, the file generated is empty:

```
import tempfile
name = tempfile.mkstemp()[1]
fh = open(name, 'wb')
fh.write(bytes(msg.message()))
fh.close()
output = File(open(name, 'rb'), msg.subject[:50])
```

I want to use a `BytesIO` instead of a temp file, but the temp file is easier for testing.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo What can I try? I'm looking for a module, not help with syntax.

Comment: Perhaps you need a newsletter? [emenica django newsletter](https://github.com/emencia/emencia-django-newsletter)

Comment: @AamirAdnan Not really - my emails, and the general infrastructure around them, don't require anything nearly that complicated.  Producing the email is easy enough, I'm just stuck with saving it to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EML file is actually a text file with name value pairs. A valid EML file would be like

```
From: test@example.com
To: test@example.com
Subject: Test

Hello world!
```

If you follow the above pattern and save it in file with .eml extension, thunderbird like email clients will parse and show them without any problem.

Comment: Would be helpful if you explain how to do it with emails that contain alternatives (html emails)

Answer (score 0):

Django's `EmailMessage.message().as_bytes()` will return the content of the .eml file. Then you just need to save the file to the directory of your choice:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage(
    'Hello',
    'Body goes here',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to3@example.com'],
)
eml_content = msg.message().as_bytes()
file_name = "/path/to/eml_output.eml"
with open(file_name, "wb") as outfile:
    outfile.write(eml_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. I found [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15793#no1) on Django site. Last [comment](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15793#comment:11) suggests using [django-eml-email-backend](https://github.com/kmike/django-eml-email-backend). It helps me and it is very useful and simple.

[Example](https://github.com/kmike/django-eml-email-backend/blob/master/README.rst):

installing:

```
$ pip install django-eml-email-backend
```

using:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'eml_email_backend.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = 'path/to/output/folder/'
```